# How to open a txt file and import lines to textbox in Windows Forms application

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

The code I am currently working with is essentially:

```
private: System::Void toolStripMenuItem3_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    OpenFileDialog^ ofd = gcnew OpenFileDialog();
    if (ofd->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK) {
        //Open file and set to textBox1 - textBox7
    }
}
```

What I am wanting to be able to do is open a text file, then read it line by line to designate which textbox the line should go into, numerically, 1-7. How should I go about doing this in VS Windows Forms Applications?

Comment: How would you put **one** line in a Windows Forms textbox? Find that out, and you'll probably have a much clearer path to the rest of your story.

Comment: @WhozCraig That is the goal here, ultimately I can fill in the rest based upon one, but I need to still be able to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

This is hardcoded to 7 lines and does no checking for end of file read, etc.

```
   private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
    {
        cli::array<TextBox^>^ tbArray = gcnew cli::array<TextBox^>(7)
        {
            textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6, textBox7
        };

        OpenFileDialog^ ofd = gcnew OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK) {
            //Open file and set to textBox1 - textBox7

            StreamReader^ dataFile = File::OpenText(ofd->FileName);


            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                tbArray[i]->Text = dataFile->ReadLine()->Trim();
            }

            dataFile->Close();

            dataFile->Dispose();

        }
    }
```